# Algorithm for time series verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a small sample of time-series data, which measures electricity values (current, voltage, active,reactive and apparent power). I measure process of appliance turning on and off. I need some algorithm, that would verify if this process was valid or not (if appliance didnt start, or started in weird way) whith multiple verified data samples.

https://i.ibb.co/pz1KM9H/timeseries.png

Another problem is, that "starting point" of measure might be different in different situation. So i am not looking for verification of values (so P.L1 can start on 1600000, but curve would be same), more like verification of the shape of that curve in graph.
I am looking for some python solution, because i process this data in pandas.

Comment: Think about [reprex]. This way you have a higher chances of getting help.

Comment: Well, i have a very limited knowledge in this topic. But i am not asking for code, i only need some sources, name/type of algorithm etc. where i can find how to do it.